# Pandas: Group by and conditional sum based on value of current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

My dataframe looks like this:

| customer_nr | order_value | year_ordered | payment_successful |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1980 | 1 |
| 1 | 75 | 2017 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 55 | 2000 | 1 |
| 2 | 300 | 2007 | 1 |
| 2 | 15 | 2010 | 0 |

I want to know the total amount a customer has successfully paid in the years before, for a specific order.

The expected output is as follows:

| customer_nr | order_value | year_ordered | payment_successful | total_successfully_previously_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1980 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 75 | 2017 | 0 | 50 |
| 1 | 10 | 2020 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 55 | 2000 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 300 | 2007 | 1 | 55 |
| 2 | 15 | 2010 | 0 | 355 |

Closest i've gotten is this:

`df.groupby(['customer_nr', 'payment_successful'], as_index=False)['order_value'].sum()`

That just gives me the summed amount successfully and unsuccessfully paid **all time** per customer. It doesn't account for selecting only previous orders to participate in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df["total_successfully_previously_paid"] = (df["payment_successful"].mul(df["order_value"])
                                                                    .groupby(df["customer_nr"])
                                                                    .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift().fillna(0))
                                            )

>>> df
   customer_nr  ...  total_successfully_previously_paid
0            1  ...                                 0.0
1            1  ...                                50.0
2            1  ...                                50.0
3            2  ...                                 0.0
4            2  ...                                55.0
5            2  ...                               355.0

[6 rows x 5 columns]
```